# Plotting network / relationship / connection type graphs in Python

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

Does anyone know a library to plot relationships between various items to show visualize their interconnectedness in Python?

I don't even now what these graphs are called. The best example is something like [Visual Thesaurus](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/).

I'm somewhat familiar with Matplotlib but haven't seen this type of plot.

Comment: I would advise using the library [pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/) : it provides an interface to GraphViz, and you can represent all kinds of relationships with it. On top of it it's pretty standard with a big community and used by a lot of people. I suggest you look at the [gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) of what you can do with GraphViz, and if that fits your needs, go for it !

Comment: It's interesting, Networkx can use GraphViz to plot.